# How can I control .NET runtime version that is being used in compiled .NET components?

Tags: .net, matlab, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, matlab-deployment

I want to compile some Matlab code in Matlab Builder NE.
In this code, I want to call .NET assemblies, using Matlab built-in ability to use .NET components : http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb58s-1.html
The process is like that:

1. C# calls Matlab compiled .NET DLL
2. MCR uses .NET assemblies to do something (As described above)
3. MCR returns answer to C#

Here is a Matlab code sample that is being compiled to .NET component, with .NET4 as target

```
function ver = GetVersion()
    NET.addAssembly('System');
    ver = char(System.Environment.Version.ToString())};
end
```

However, when this simple code is compiled, by taking a look at *ver*,I am realizing that it uses .NET 2 instead of .NET 4.

When I use it directly from Matlab, I get version 4.
How can I control the .NET runtime version in compiled DLLs?

Answer (score 1):

### on the same computer?The command "mcc" make a version of the latest supported version on the target machine.You can choose a version.

Just now I have a test with my computer,User mcc to set the version of **.Net 2.0** to complier

```
mcc -W 'dotnet:TestVersion,Version,2.0,private' -d 'C:\Users\HW-WIN7-TEMP\Documents\MATLAB\TestVersion\src' -T 'link:lib' -v 'class{Version:C:\Users\HW-WIN7-TEMP\Documents\MATLAB\GetVersion.m}'
```

And I use target version 3.5 to run my C# program.Get the same result.

> > > ver = GetVersion() ver =
> > >       2.0.50727.5448

Comment: I did choose, and put .NET4 as the target.

Comment: And yes, it is on the same computer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sorry,my Matlab version is R2009a,I cannot try further.